# To disable Auto lock in windows 2008 machines through Active Directory Domain Controller

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-controller

In all my 158 machines which are under domain,i need to disable automatic lock. How can i implement this through Domain Controller.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new GPO and edit the following setting:

User Config -> Policies -> Admin Templates -> All Settings

Set 'Password protect the screen saver' to disabled.

Test by applying to selected users before rolling out to everyone.

*This assumes you are rolling it out to Windows 7 machines.*